# Pine Script / External Data Alternative

Tags: pine-script

As far as I know, Pine Script does not accept external data currently. I have static x1v and x2v coordinates for 1 trendline each for 2000 symbols that I would like to input into Pine Script for each symbol. When syminfo.tickerid matches with a string for these values, I would like Pine Script to plot trend lines only for the respective symbol.

One approach I tried is as following:

```
//@version=4
study('TEST', overlay=true, title = "test")

x1v = int(na)
x2v = int(na)

x1v := iff(syminfo.ticker == 'AAPL', 20,x1v)
x2v := iff(syminfo.ticker == 'AAPL', 6,x2v)
x1v := iff(syminfo.ticker == 'MSFT', 20,x1v)
x2v := iff(syminfo.ticker == 'MSFT', 6,x2v)
x1v := iff(syminfo.ticker == 'OPEN', 20,x1v)
x2v := iff(syminfo.ticker == 'OPEN', 6,x2v)
x1v := iff(syminfo.ticker == 'SPY', 20,x1v)
x2v := iff(syminfo.ticker == 'SPY', 6,x2v)

myline = line.new(x1=bar_index-x1v, y1=high[x1v], x2=bar_index-x2v, y2=high)
line.set_extend(myline, extend.both)
line.delete(myline[1])
```

Doing this for 2000 symbols, produces 4000+ lines and Pine Script does not accept it saying:
**Script has too many local variables (5187) in "#f2": #mut_0, #mut_1, #mut_0, #mut_1, #mut_0... The limit is 1100**

Even though the local variables are the same x1v and x2v.

Is there any other option to overcome this or to make this more compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.
I've included 2 methods:

- `f_fill_array_all_tickers()`

  - Looks cleaner
  - Might be slower.
- `f_fill_array_current_ticker_only()`

  - Looks less clean
  - Might be faster, depending on how far down the list the ticker is.

The script has an input checkbox `i_fill_array_all_tickers` to let you choose between the 2 methods.

I'd personally go for `f_fill_array_all_tickers()` because of readability/maintainability.

```
//@version=4
study("Lines", "LI", true)

var bool        i_fill_array_all_tickers    = input(false, "Fill array with ALL tickers")

var string[]    a_ticker    = array.new_string()
var int[]       a_x1        = array.new_int()
var int[]       a_x2        = array.new_int()

var line        myLine      = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.both)

f_add(_ticker, _x1, _x2) =>
    if array.includes(a_ticker, _ticker)
        // update existing ticker
        idx = array.indexof(a_ticker, _ticker)
        array.set(a_x1, idx, _x1)
        array.set(a_x2, idx, _x2)
    else
        // insert new ticker
        array.push(a_ticker,    _ticker)
        array.push(a_x1,        _x1)
        array.push(a_x2,        _x2)


f_fill_array_all_tickers() =>
    //fill array with data for ALL tickers
    f_add("AAPL", 20, 6)
    f_add("MSFT", 20, 6)
    f_add("OPEN", 20, 6)
    f_add("SPY" , 20, 6)
    
f_fill_array_current_ticker_only() =>
    //fill array with data for only the CURRENT tickers
    if      syminfo.ticker == "AAPL" 
        f_add(syminfo.ticker, 20, 6)
    else if syminfo.ticker == "MSFT"
        f_add(syminfo.ticker, 20, 6)
    else if syminfo.ticker == "OPEN"
        f_add(syminfo.ticker, 20, 6)
    else if syminfo.ticker == "MSFT"
        f_add(syminfo.ticker, 20, 6)

f_fill_array() =>
    if i_fill_array_all_tickers
        f_fill_array_all_tickers()
    else
        f_fill_array_current_ticker_only()
        
if barstate.isfirst
    f_fill_array() 

if barstate.islast and array.includes(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
    idx = array.indexof(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
    x1  = array.get(a_x1, idx)
    x2  = array.get(a_x2, idx)
    line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index - x1, high[x1])
    line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index - x2, high)
```

Minimized code

```
//@version=4
study("Lines", "LI", true)

var a_ticker = array.new_string()
var a_x1 = array.new_int()
var a_x2 = array.new_int()
var myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.both)

ai(a,v) => array.includes(a,v)
ax(a,v) => array.indexof(a,v)
as(a,i,v) => array.set(a,i,v)
ag(a,i) => array.get(a,i)
ap(a,v) => array.push(a,v)

f(t,a,b) =>
    if ai(a_ticker,t)
        i = ax(a_ticker,t),as(a_x1,i,a),as(a_x2,i,b) 
    else 
        ap(a_ticker,t),ap(a_x1,a),ap(a_x2,b)

a() => f("AAPL",20,6),f("MSFT",20,6),f("OPEN",20,6),f("SPY",20,6)
    
if barstate.isfirst
    a() 

if barstate.islast and ai(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
    idx = ax(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
    x1  = ag(a_x1, idx)
    x2  = ag(a_x2, idx)
    line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index - x1, high[x1])
    line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index - x2, high)
```

This seems to work, with 10 lines of 100 elements each

```
//@version=4
study("Lines", "LI", true)

var a_ticker = array.new_string()
var a_x1 = array.new_int()
var a_x2 = array.new_int()
var myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.both)

ai(a,v) => array.includes(a,v)
ax(a,v) => array.indexof(a,v)
as(a,i,v) => array.set(a,i,v)
ag(a,i) => array.get(a,i)
ap(a,v) => array.push(a,v)

f(t,a,b) =>
    if ai(a_ticker,t)
        i = ax(a_ticker,t),as(a_x1,i,a),as(a_x2,i,b) 
    else 
        ap(a_ticker,t),ap(a_x1,a),ap(a_x2,b)

a() => 
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6)

if barstate.isfirst
    a()
    
if barstate.islast and ai(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
    idx = ax(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
    x1  = ag(a_x1, idx)
    x2  = ag(a_x2, idx)
    line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index - x1, high[x1])
    line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index - x2, high)
```

Little improvement.
When calling `a()` on the last bar instead of `barstate.isfirst`, the runtime doesn't have to keep the arrays in memory on all the historical bars.

```
if barstate.islast
    a()
    if ai(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        idx = ax(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        x1  = ag(a_x1, idx)
        x2  = ag(a_x2, idx)
        line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index - x1, high[x1])
        line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index - x2, high)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this approach. When using f_fill_array_all_tickers() and creating 2 functions with 1000 tickers+coordinates in each, Pine Script cannot compile as "Compiled script code is too long: 99872. The limit is 60000." Similar approach produces this with f_fill_array_current_ticker_only(): "Script has too many local scopes: 851. The limit is 500."

Comment: I've added a minimized code example. Can you fit your 1000 tickers now?

Comment: Appreciate this! Same thing unfortunately. I added 1000 elements for a() as per your code and then also added b() and c() functions with the same number of elements. I've put a() b() and c() under "if barstate.isfirst" and Pine cannot compile it: "Compiled script code is too long: 159664. The limit is 60000." Is there maybe a way to make Pine completely ignore a function based on the first letter of syminfo.ticker for example so I can add functions with 1000 elements each without running into this error?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _Is there maybe a way to make Pine completely ignore a function based on syminfo.ticker so I can add functions with 1000 elements each without running into this error?_

Comment: Is there a way to add several functions with 1000 elements each, but only access the relevant function based on the first letter of syminfo.ticker and to ignore the other functions completely while compiling to avoid this error?

Comment: Will check. In the meantime, I added a version with 10 lines with 100 elements each, which seems to compile.

Comment: Yes this version compiles with 1000 elements. For another 1000 elements you need to add a separate function like a() ( let's call if b() )with the same content which compiles too if it is not accessed anywhere. Once a() and b() are under barstate.isfirst then this no longer compiles. Maybe there is a way to only access a() or b() based on the first letter of syminfo.ticker or any other way? Although I am not sure how to tell the compiler to completely ignore the other function then.

Comment: That can be done, but it'll make no difference, because the compiler takes into account ALL the code that you type. I guess the max number of characters in a script is 60K.