# How to overcome "Compiled script code is too long" in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Trying the following based on this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66356225/pine-script-external-data-alternative) from Bjorn to include more array elements in the code. The below theoretical example includes 1000 in function a() and 500 in b). PineScript cannot compile this as Compiled script code is too long: 79979. The limit is 60000. However, the number of characters with spaces is only 23115. Is there anything that can be done to include more as I need to include 4000 elements?

If everything below line 49 (`from if barstate.islast and syminfo.ticker == "SPY"`) is excluded, the code compiles as b() is never accessed. Is there maybe a way only to access b() if the first letter of syminfo.ticker matches "S" for example?

```
//@version=4
study("Lines", "LI", true)

var a_ticker = array.new_string()
var a_x1 = array.new_int()
var a_x2 = array.new_int()
var myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.both)

ai(a,v) => array.includes(a,v)
ax(a,v) => array.indexof(a,v)
as(a,i,v) => array.set(a,i,v)
ag(a,i) => array.get(a,i)
ap(a,v) => array.push(a,v)

f(t,a,b) =>
    if ai(a_ticker,t)
        i = ax(a_ticker,t),as(a_x1,i,a),as(a_x2,i,b) 
    else 
        ap(a_ticker,t),ap(a_x1,a),ap(a_x2,b)

a() => 
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6)

b() => 
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),

if barstate.islast and syminfo.ticker == "AAPL"
    a()
    if ai(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        idx = ax(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        x1  = ag(a_x1, idx)
        x2  = ag(a_x2, idx)
        line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index - x1, high[x1])
        line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index - x2, high)

if barstate.islast and syminfo.ticker == "SPY"
    b()
    if ai(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        idx = ax(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        x1  = ag(a_x1, idx)
        x2  = ag(a_x2, idx)
        line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index - x1, high[x1])
        line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index - x2, high)
```

**Edit 1:**

Based on Bjorn's solution, I am trying to use the same approach for y1 and y2 price values of the trend line which should be *float* (to use price values) while keeping x1 and x2 as static timestamp values for the trend line. I adjusted the code to accept *float* instead of *int*, but only *int* seems to be accepted. Is there something missing? Is the function *f_str2int* needed for *float* values?

```
//@version=4
study("Lines", "LI", true)

x1_date = timestamp(2020, 10, 30, 9, 30)
x2_date = timestamp(2021, 2, 16, 9, 30)

var string[]    a_ticker            = array.new_string()
var float[]     a_y1                = array.new_float()
var float[]     a_y2                = array.new_float()
var string[]    a_str               = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_digits_str        = array.new_string()
var float[]     a_digits_float      = array.new_float()
var line        myLine              = line.new(x1_date, na, x2_date, na, extend=extend.both, color = color.yellow, xloc = xloc.bar_time)

var string[]    a_str_set_ticker    = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_str_set_y1        = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_str_set_y2        = array.new_string()


// Initializes the a_digits_float array
f_init_digits_float() =>
    for x = 0 to 9
        array.push(a_digits_str, tostring(x))
        array.push(a_digits_float, x)


// Converts a string containing an digit, to an integer
f_digitstr2int(_dstr) => 
    array.get(a_digits_float, array.indexof(a_digits_str, _dstr))


// Converts a string containing an integer, to an integer
f_str2int(_s) => 
    float multiplier = 1
    float number = 0

    a = str.split(_s,"")
    array.reverse(a)

    for x = 0 to array.size(a)-1
        digit_str = array.get(a,x)
        number := number + multiplier * f_digitstr2int(digit_str)
        multiplier := multiplier * 10
        
    number     

// Initialize the data
f_init_data() =>
    array.push(a_str_set_ticker, "AAPL,AMZN,SPY")
    array.push(a_str_set_y1, "121,3228,322.2")
    array.push(a_str_set_y2, "119.1,3210.8,394.9")

if barstate.islast
    // Initialization
    f_init_digits_float()
    f_init_data()

    // Process the data
    for z = 0 to array.size(a_str_set_ticker)-1
        a_ticker := array.concat(str.split(array.get(a_str_set_ticker, z),","), a_ticker)

        a_str := str.split(array.get(a_str_set_y1, z),",")
        for i = 0 to array.size(a_str)-1
            array.push(a_y1,f_str2int(array.get(a_str,i)))

        a_str := str.split(array.get(a_str_set_y2, z),",")
        for i = 0 to array.size(a_str)-1
            array.push(a_y2,f_str2int(array.get(a_str,i)))

    // Draw line
    if array.includes(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        idx = array.indexof(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        y1  = array.get(a_y1, idx)
        y2  = array.get(a_y2, idx)
        line.set_y1(myLine, y1)
        line.set_y2(myLine, y2)
```

**Edit 2:**

Based on Bjorn's approach for *float* I am trying to plot 3 lines for the same symbol, but it seems that only the first set of array elements is processed? Is there a way to produce more lines for the same symbols (either 1, 2, or up to 3 lines based on the data)? The relevant arrays would include the below:

```
// Initialize the data
f_init_data() =>
    // 4000 tickers, broken down into 5 sets, because a string has a max size of 4096 characters.
    // 800 tickers, set 1
    array.push(a_str_set_ticker, "QQQ,QQQ,QQQ,AMZN,AMZN")
    array.push(a_str_set_y1, "267,300,222,3000,2000")
    array.push(a_str_set_y2, "338.2,200,111,2500,1000")
```

Comment: Created 2nd answer for the y-value problem (your Edit 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your Edit 1.
Couldn't update my original answer, because of the 30K character limit, so had to post a new answer.

Added `f_str2float()` for y-values.
Example script:

```
//@version=4
study("Lines", "LI", true)

var string[]    a_ticker            = array.new_string()
var int[]       a_x1                = array.new_int()
var int[]       a_x2                = array.new_int()
var float[]     a_y1                = array.new_float()
var float[]     a_y2                = array.new_float()
var string[]    a_str               = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_digits_str        = array.new_string()
var int[]       a_digits_int        = array.new_int()
var line        myLine              = line.new(na, na, na, na)//, extend=extend.both)

var string[]    a_str_set_ticker    = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_str_set_x1        = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_str_set_x2        = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_str_set_y1        = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_str_set_y2        = array.new_string()


// Initializes the a_digits_int array
f_init_digits_int() =>
    for x = 0 to 9
        array.push(a_digits_str, tostring(x))
        array.push(a_digits_int, x)

// Converts a string containing a digit, to an integer
f_digitstr2int(_dstr) => 
    array.get(a_digits_int, array.indexof(a_digits_str, _dstr))

// Converts a string containing an integer, to an integer
f_str2int(_s) => 
    int multiplier = 1
    int number = 0

    // Initialize the a_digits_int array in case it hasn't been done yet.
    if not array.size(a_digits_int) 
        f_init_digits_int() 
        
    a = str.split(_s,"")
    array.reverse(a)

    for x = 0 to array.size(a)-1
        digit_str = array.get(a,x)
        number := number + multiplier * f_digitstr2int(digit_str)
        multiplier := multiplier * 10
        
    number        

// Converts a string containing a float, to a float
f_str2float(_s) =>
    float   number          = na
    string  s_absolute      = str.replace_all(_s,"-","")
    bool    is_negative     = str.length(s_absolute) != str.length(_s)
    
    a_split = str.split(s_absolute,".")
    if array.size(a_split) > 1 // _s has a decimal separator
        number := f_str2int(array.get(a_split,0)) + f_str2int(array.get(a_split,1)) / pow(10,str.length(array.get(a_split,1)))
    else // _s does not have a decimal separator, so it's an integer
        number := f_str2int(_s)
    
    number * (is_negative ? -1 : 1)

// Initialize the data
f_init_data() =>
    // 4000 tickers, broken down into 5 sets, because a string has a max size of 4096 characters.
    // 800 tickers, set 1
    array.push(a_str_set_ticker, "AAPL,AMZN,QQQ")
    array.push(a_str_set_x1, "20,30,40")
    array.push(a_str_set_x2, "2,3,4")
    array.push(a_str_set_y1, "100.22,3000.33,300.44")
    array.push(a_str_set_y2, "140.22,3500.33,350.44")

if barstate.islast
    // Initialization
    f_init_data()

    // Process the data
    for z = 0 to array.size(a_str_set_ticker)-1
        a_ticker := array.concat(str.split(array.get(a_str_set_ticker, z),","), a_ticker)

        a_str := str.split(array.get(a_str_set_x1, z),",")
        for i = 0 to array.size(a_str)-1
            array.push(a_x1,f_str2int(array.get(a_str,i)))

        a_str := str.split(array.get(a_str_set_x2, z),",")
        for i = 0 to array.size(a_str)-1
            array.push(a_x2,f_str2int(array.get(a_str,i)))

        a_str := str.split(array.get(a_str_set_y1, z),",")
        for i = 0 to array.size(a_str)-1
            array.push(a_y1,f_str2float(array.get(a_str,i)))

        a_str := str.split(array.get(a_str_set_y2, z),",")
        for i = 0 to array.size(a_str)-1
            array.push(a_y2,f_str2float(array.get(a_str,i)))

    // Draw line
    if array.includes(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        idx = array.indexof(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        x1  = array.get(a_x1, idx)
        x2  = array.get(a_x2, idx)
        y1  = array.get(a_y1, idx)
        y2  = array.get(a_y2, idx)
        line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index - x1, y1)
        line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index - x2, y2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it doesn't work, because as I've commented in your previous question, the compiler takes all code in the script into consideration when compiling. Even if it's not called.

Here's an example that differentiates on the first letter of the symbol, but it won't compile, because the total codebase is too large.

```
//@version=4
study("Lines", "LI", true)

var a_ticker = array.new_string()
var a_x1 = array.new_int()
var a_x2 = array.new_int()
var myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.both)

ai(a,v) => array.includes(a,v)
ax(a,v) => array.indexof(a,v)
as(a,i,v) => array.set(a,i,v)
ag(a,i) => array.get(a,i)
ap(a,v) => array.push(a,v)

f(t,a,b) =>
    if ai(a_ticker,t)
        i = ax(a_ticker,t),as(a_x1,i,a),as(a_x2,i,b) 
    else 
        ap(a_ticker,t),ap(a_x1,a),ap(a_x2,b)

a() => 
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),
    f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6),f("AAPL",20,6)

b() => 
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),
    f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6),f("SPY",20,6)

if barstate.islast
    first_letter = array.get(str.split(syminfo.ticker, ""),0)

    if first_letter == "A"
        a()
    
    if first_letter == "S"
        b()

    if array.size(a_ticker) > 0
        if ai(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
            idx = ax(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
            x1  = ag(a_x1, idx)
            x2  = ag(a_x2, idx)
            line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index - x1, high[x1])
            line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index - x2, high)
```

I'm afraid we'll have to wait until TradingView makes it possible to read from external sources.

Edit:
I've managed to create a solution that compiles, while holding the requested 4000 tickers.
Had to put the [script on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/T63JpRye), because apparently answers on StackOverflow have a limit of 30K characters. Limits everywhere, not only in Pine :)

Edit2:
In response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370664/how-to-overcome-compiled-script-code-is-too-long-in-pine-script/66370766?noredirect=1#comment117360375_66370766).
There was indeed a small error in the code.
The arguments of the `array.concat()` function needed to be switched.

From

```
a_ticker := array.concat(a_ticker, str.split(array.get(a_str_set_ticker, z),","))
```

To

```
a_ticker := array.concat(str.split(array.get(a_str_set_ticker, z),","), a_ticker)
```

Here's the full code with only the 3 tickers from your example.

```
//@version=4
study("Lines", "LI", true)

var string[]    a_ticker            = array.new_string()
var int[]       a_x1                = array.new_int()
var int[]       a_x2                = array.new_int()
var string[]    a_str               = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_digits_str        = array.new_string()
var int[]       a_digits_int        = array.new_int()
var line        myLine              = line.new(na, na, na, na)//, extend=extend.both)

var string[]    a_str_set_ticker    = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_str_set_x1        = array.new_string()
var string[]    a_str_set_x2        = array.new_string()


// Initializes the a_digits_int array
f_init_digits_int() =>
    for x = 0 to 9
        array.push(a_digits_str, tostring(x))
        array.push(a_digits_int, x)


// Converts a string containing an digit, to an integer
f_digitstr2int(_dstr) => 
    array.get(a_digits_int, array.indexof(a_digits_str, _dstr))


// Converts a string containing an integer, to an integer
f_str2int(_s) => 
    int multiplier = 1
    int number = 0

    a = str.split(_s,"")
    array.reverse(a)

    for x = 0 to array.size(a)-1
        digit_str = array.get(a,x)
        number := number + multiplier * f_digitstr2int(digit_str)
        multiplier := multiplier * 10
        
    number        

// Initialize the data
f_init_data() =>
    // 4000 tickers, broken down into 5 sets, because a string has a max size of 4096 characters.
    // 800 tickers, set 1
    array.push(a_str_set_ticker, "AAPL,AMZN,QQQ")
    array.push(a_str_set_x1, "20,30,40")
    array.push(a_str_set_x2, "2,3,4")

if barstate.islast
    // Initialization
    f_init_digits_int()
    f_init_data()

    // Process the data
    for z = 0 to array.size(a_str_set_ticker)-1
        a_ticker := array.concat(str.split(array.get(a_str_set_ticker, z),","), a_ticker)

        a_str := str.split(array.get(a_str_set_x1, z),",")
        for i = 0 to array.size(a_str)-1
            array.push(a_x1,f_str2int(array.get(a_str,i)))

        a_str := str.split(array.get(a_str_set_x2, z),",")
        for i = 0 to array.size(a_str)-1
            array.push(a_x2,f_str2int(array.get(a_str,i)))

    // Draw line
    if array.includes(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        idx = array.indexof(a_ticker, syminfo.ticker)
        x1  = array.get(a_x1, idx)
        x2  = array.get(a_x2, idx)
        line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index - x1, high[x1])
        line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index - x2, high)
```

The [script on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/T63JpRye) has also been updated.

Comment: I've managed to create a solution that compiles, while holding the requested 4000 tickers. See pastebin script.

Comment: This is genius!

Comment: In your code, the elements for array.push(a_str_set_x1) and array.push(a_str_set_x2) are written in the same order as the elements of array.push(a_str_set_ticker), but they are processed in an inverted order. This is noticeable when you use different symbols with different x1 and x2 values. For example: AAPL,AMZN,QQQ would have x1 as 20,30,40 written in the code (in that order), but 40 is processed for AAPL and 20 for QQQ. Is there a way to keep x1 and x2 in the same order when the code is processed?

Comment: Fixed. See Edit2 in my answer.

Comment: Appreciate your help! I can confirm that this works. Added Edit 1 to my question as I am trying to use the same approach with float values instead of int for y1 and y2 of the trend line while keeping x1 and x2 static.

Comment: `str2int()` works only for integers. Will add a `float` conversion, but might not be today. In the meantime, you can check this [String to Number](https://www.tradingview.com/script/nnED9HgA-String-to-Number/) script for some inspiration :)

Comment: Appreciate your help and input Bjorn!

Comment: Added Edit 2 to my question - is there a way to use the same symbols several times for several lines or can only 1 symbol be processed in this approach?

Comment: Yes, I have a solution. Could you make a new question for this please? This is getting a bit crowded.

Comment: Certainly, I started a separate question for this: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431481/using-multiple-array-elements-to-produce-multiple-lines-for-the-same-symbols-pi)